# Reducing down Breakpoints in Bootstrap

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have an existing site with legacy code that I can't edit (for reasons I can't get into here). The site uses bootstrap 4, but I would like to make a one-line modification that reduces the number of breakpoints from 5 to 3. I can accomplish this with a one-line change easily by doing this:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 768px,
    md: 1200px,
    lg: 1200px,
    xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

This accomplishes exactly what I want. It basically makes obsolete all the code that references two additional breakpoints that I don't want. However, the only downside is that it spits out annoying warnings about a hundred times every time I compile:

```
WARNING: Invalid value for $grid-breakpoints: This map must be in ascending order, but key 'xl' has value 1200px which isn't greater than 1200px, the value of the previous key 'lg' !
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to suppress these warnings? (compiling with `npm run` btw)
2. Is there a more elegant way to remove the extra breakpoints (keeping in mind i can't do a find and replace across the whole code base and remove those references to `lg` `md` etc)

Comment: use 1199.98, 1199.99, 1200, it will remove your error

Comment: this worked great, thanks!

Comment: Accept my answer, if I helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 1199.98, 1199.99, 1200 as breakpoints, It will remove your error.